# Convert a opengl coordinate to a pixel format

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a screen of an Android smartphone with 1280x720 resolution and I have an Activity with a OpenGL component that has a rectangular object on the screen, this object will not be centralized, and the position of the margins justando I got the following configuration: Left:. 0.19f Top: 0.05 f, Right: 0.01 f, Botton: 0.05 f.

But I do not know what these numbers represent exactly, I was wondering if it is possible to know the exact values ​​of these margins in pixels?

If you need any other info, just ask, I do not know opengl but I'm trying to use an existing code that uses opengl.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. These are the Viewport's rectangle expressed as a fraction, or percent, of it's parent container (Which should be the activity covering the 1280x720 resolution screen you mentioned). Therefore, the number of pixels can be calculated as:

```
Left:   (0.19 * 1280) = 243.2 px
Top:    (0.05 * 720)  = 36    px
Right:  (0.01 * 1280) = 12.8  px
Bottom: (0.05 * 720)  = 36    px
```

Note that the Right and Bottom sides are the pixels FROM the right and bottom sides of the screen. If you wanted their pixel coordinates, you would have to subtract them from the screen dimensions.

```
Right:  (1280 - 12.8) = 1267.2 px
Bottom: (720 - 36)    = 684 px
```

Or, in general,

```
leftPixels = leftPercent * screenWidth;
topPixels = topPercent * screenHeight;
rightPixels = screenWidth - (rightPercent * screenWidth);
bottomPixels = screenHeight - (bottomPercent * screenHeight);
```